# Repeat 1D array to 2D array with shifted rows

Tags: python, numpy

I want to take an array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and turn it into a 5x5 array like this:

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
 [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
 [4, 5, 0, 0 ,0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How can I do this with `numpy`?

I also want to be able to use an arbitrary array like `a = [1, 6, 2, 3, 8]` and get:

```py
[[1, 6, 2, 3, 8],
 [6, 2, 3, 8, 0],
 [2, 3, 8, 0, 0],
 [3, 8, 0, 0, 0],
 [8, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Disclaimer:

The following solution only works if you only need a *view*. This solution does not return a *writeable* array. If you need a writeable array, you can simply pass the view to the array constructor: `np.array(array_view)`, but at that point, the `linalg.hankel` from @loopywalt's solution is a better approach, unless you want to use any of the fun features I add.

### If all you need is a view

Here's a solution which works for arbitrary 1D arrays and is supremely fast:

```py
def fast_hankel_view(a: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    arr = np.append(a, np.zeros(a.size - 1, a.dtype))
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, a.size)
```

Output:

```py
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> fast_hankel_view(a)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> a = np.array([1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8])
>>> fast_hankel_view(a)
array([[1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8],
       [4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0],
       [3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0],
       [5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Small benchmark for an array of 100,000 random integers:

```py
In [3]: x = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1, 100000), dtype="uint8")
In [4]: %timeit fast_hankel_view(x)
25.8 µs ± 165 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Again, this is so fast because it's only constructing a *view* of the input array `x`:

```py
In [5]: h = fast_hankel_view(x)

In [6]: h += 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ce0b251d63e1> in <module>
----> 1 h += 1

ValueError: output array is read-only
```

To reiterate, however, you *can* get a writeable array from the output by passing the view to the `np.array()` constructor:

```py
In [7]: x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])

In [8]: h = np.array(fast_hankel_view(x))

In [9]: h
Out[9]:
array([[1, 3, 5, 7],
       [3, 5, 7, 0],
       [5, 7, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 0, 0]])

In [10]: h += 1

In [11]: h
Out[11]:
array([[2, 4, 6, 8],
       [4, 6, 8, 1],
       [6, 8, 1, 1],
       [8, 1, 1, 1]])
```

### Some fun modifications

With a small modification, you can also reflect across the diagonal, if you wish, or pad with another array (note that the total number of elements of both arrays taken together must be odd in order for the resultant to be square):

```py
import numpy as np


def fast_hankel_view(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, (x.size + 1) // 2)


def hankel_view_builder(a: np.ndarray, pad="zeros") -> np.ndarray:
    if type(pad) == np.ndarray:
        arr = np.append(a, pad)
    elif pad == "zeros":
        arr = np.append(a, np.zeros(a.size - 1, a.dtype))
    elif pad == "reflect":
        arr = np.append(a, np.flip(a)[1:])
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid pad type!")
    return fast_hankel_view(arr)
```

A nice benefit of appending to two arrays and using `sliding_window_view` is that you can supply arrays of differing length (doing this with scipy's `linalg.hankel` returns unintuitive results, in my opinion):

```py
In [11]: x
Out[11]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [12]: y
Out[12]: array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [13]: hankel_view_builder(x, y)  # note the parity of |x| + |y|
Out[13]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [14]: hankel_view_builder(y, "reflect")
Out[14]:
array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7],
       [7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6],
       [8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
       [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]])

In [15]: hankel_view_builder(y)
Out[15]:
array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: @zief26 I've updated my solution to reflect your new requirements.

Comment: What do you mean by needing twice the amount of memory? The sliding view stores 2n-1 elements but that compares to n^2 elements for conventional arrays. What makes direct comparisons a bit tricky is that you cannot freely modify the view; it will keep the "Hankel structure" no matter what, which may or may be not what you want.

Comment: Well there's the intermediate step of appending an array of length `n - 1` to an array of length `n`, for an array of length `2n - 1`. I see your point though, since the end result is still larger in memory than the intermediate step so I guess it's a bit pointless to mention.

Comment: Nvm, I just realized what you were saying.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use scipy:

```
from scipy import linalg

linalg.hankel([1,2,3,4,5])
# array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
#        [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
#        [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
#        [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If not:

```
def hankel(a):
    n = len(a)
    out = np.zeros((n,n),int)
    out.ravel()[:-1].reshape(n+1,n-1)[1:,0] = a[-1]
    np.copyto(out.ravel()[:1-2*n].reshape(n-1,n-1),a[:-1],where=np.tri(n-1,dtype=bool).T)
    return out                                

hankel([1,2,3,4,5])
# array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
#        [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
#        [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
#        [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I hope you get a sufficient number of upvotes to be top of the answers. WIthout knowing the name of this matrix it's hard to find [scipy.linalg.hankel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html)

Comment: I get an `IndexError` trying to use your homegrown solution.

Comment: `scipy.linalg.hankel()` is also quite slow for large arrays, but a very nice solution regardless, and TIL about the Hankel matrix!

Comment: @ddejohn I'm curious why it doesn't work for you. Could you be more specific? It works just fine for me.

Comment: Hmm. I'm unable to reproduce. Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 2):

With [`np.add.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
r = np.add.outer(a,a) - 1
np.where(r <= len(a), r, 0)
```

Output

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

More general for constantly increasing integer ranges

```
a = [-2, -1, 0 , 1, 2, 3]
r = np.add.outer(a,a) - np.min(a)
np.where(r <= np.max(a), r, 0)
```

Output

```
array([[-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

---

For arbitrary arrays

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8]) 
x = np.arange(len(a))
r = np.add.outer(x,x)
idx = np.where(r <= len(x)-1, r, 0)
np.where(r <= len(x)-1, np.full(r.shape, a)[np.arange(len(a)),idx], 0)
```

Output

```
array([[1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8],
       [4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0],
       [3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0],
       [5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Very clever to use `np.outer` here. I still wonder if a more direct method exists.

Comment: @ddejohn - Usually there is a smarter way with `numpy` that I haven't seen yet

Comment: it doesn't work for me, because my array consist like this, example

array([1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 8])

so if we use np.where all 8 will change with 0 too

Comment: @zief26 - I added a solution for arbitrary arrays which is not optimal but uses the same approach.

Comment: @ddejohn more likely due to the fact that you are not creating a full contiguous array but a much smaller array with clever metadata (which is fine for many but not all applications).

Comment: Yep, I'm dumb. I didn't think about the fact that I was working with a view. Damn, lol, I'm super embarassed.

Comment: @ddejohn no need to be. For many situations, for example, if there is no need to modify the matrix it's a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary arrays where you want to obtain a shift along axis 0:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
padded = np.append(np.zeros((1, a.size)), a)
print("padded:")
print(padded)
duplicated = np.tile(padded, a.size)
print("duplicated:")
print(duplicated)
resized = np.resize(duplicated, (a.size+1, padded.size - 1))
print("resized:")
print(resized)
flipped = resized[::-1]
print("flipped:")
print(flipped)
result = flipped[:a.size,:a.size]
print("result:")
print(result)
```

Output

```
padded:
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
duplicated:
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3.
 4. 5.]
resized:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
flipped:
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [4. 5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]]
result:
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [2. 3. 4. 5. 0.]
 [3. 4. 5. 0. 0.]
 [4. 5. 0. 0. 0.]
 [5. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = np. array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
# Convert 1D array to a 2D numpy array of 2 rows and 3 columns.
arr_2d = np. reshape(arr, (2, 5))
print(arr_2d)
```

You can use reshape function. Populate the array as your requirement and then use reshape.

Comment: Did you inadvertently post the answer to another question here? This doesn't look like an answer to this question.